# Intel Vtune on amd processors

Tags: call-graph, amd-processor

I've installed Intel Vtune Analyzer 9 to get call-graph and counter-monitor data from a win32 application on a Windows 7 PC with AMD Turion X2 TL-58 processor but it gives an error saying :"The CPU architecture can't be identified properly, data collection is not available". Is there a similar tool for AMD platforms?

Answer (score 10):

AMD uProf is the profiler for AMD processors. It can be downloaded from [here](https://developer.amd.com/amd-uprof/).

Answer (score 3):

AMD CodeAnalyst Performance Analyzer does similar things for AMD.

You can find it at [this link](http://www.amddevcentral.com/CPU/CODEANALYST/Pages/default.aspx). It is not as full featured but seems to get the performance counters data you are looking for.